# Pandas Mean Across Two Data Frames on Similar Columns only

Tags: python, pandas

I have a unique requirement , where i need mean of common columns (per row) from two dataframes.

I can not think of a pythonic way of doing this. I know i can loop through two data frames and find common columns  and then get mean of rows where key matches.

Assuming I have below Data Frames:
DF1:

```
Key A   B   C   D   E
K1  2   3   4   5   8
K2  2   3   4   5   8
K3  2   3   4   5   8
K4  2   3   4   5   8
```

DF2:

```
Key A   B   C   D
K1  4   7   4   7
K2  4   7   4   7
K3  4   7   4   7
K4  4   7   4   7
```

The result DF should be the mean values of the two DF , each column per row where Key matches. 
ResultDF:

```
 Key    A   B   C   D
    K1  3   5   4   6
    K2  3   5   4   6
    K3  3   5   4   6
    K4  3   5   4   6
```

I know i should put sample code here , but i can not think of any logic for achieving this till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.add` using `Key` as the indexes:

```
df1.set_index('Key').add(df2.set_index('Key')).dropna(axis=1) / 2

     A  B  C  D
Key            
K1   3  5  4  6
K2   3  5  4  6
K3   3  5  4  6
K4   3  5  4  6
```

---

Alternative with `concat` + `groupby`.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).dropna(axis=1).groupby('Key').mean()

     A  B  C  D
Key            
K1   3  5  4  6
K2   3  5  4  6
K3   3  5  4  6
K4   3  5  4  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the to data frames together then use the pandas [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply) function then add a `lambda` in it then divide `x` with two:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4,4]})
print((df1+df2).apply(lambda x: x/2))
```

Output:

```
   A
0  3.0
1  3.0
```

*Note: this is just with a dummy data frame*

Comment: Looks good , and then I can drop `NaN` , which will be for those columns which do not match .   but how about the key to be matching

Comment: This is good if only all my columns are numbers , throws error when one of the column of not number type i.e. String.

Comment: @RehanAzher i think coldspeed's answer is the correct answer